# "to argue a view": Is this correct and common?

Tags: word-choice

Is the phrase "they argue different views" acceptable?

When I google the phrase "argue a view" with quotations, I found relatively small number of results and some of them had a clause after "view" (e.g. *They argue the view is not correct.*), which I believe to be a correct usage.

But at the same time, I did find a phrase *Can you argue a view that is not your own?*, where the verb "argue" takes "view" as its object.

So, my question is "is it ungrammatical/semantically unacceptable/very uncommon for the verb *to argue* to take *view* as its object, or is it totally fine?"

Answer (score 1):

Let me first parse your examples.

> Ex. 1. They argue different views.

*They* is the subject, *argue* is the verb, and *views* is the direct object.

> Ex. 2. They argue the view is not correct.

*They* is the subject, *argue* is the verb, and the noun clause *[that] the view is not correct* is the direct object. The word *that* is implied (this is fairly standard usage, see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_relative_clauses#That_as_relativizer_instead_of_relative_pronoun)).

Here is the OED entry [online version, sorry if you do not have access] with some entries truncated.

> (1) to make good an accusation against, prove wrong or guilty.
>
> (2) *trans.* to accuse, impeach, arraign.
>
> (3) to prove or evince; to afford good ground for inferring.
>
> (4) *intr.* to bring forward reasons concerning a matter in debate.
>
> (5) to discuss the pros and cons of.
>
> (6) *with subord. clause.* to maintain, by adducing reasons, the proposition or opinion that.
>
> (7) to bring forward as a reason (for or against).
>
> (8) *to argue (a thing) away, off, etc.*: to get rid of by argument.
>
> (9) *to argue (a person) into or out of*: to persuade him by argument into, or out of, a course of action.

Example 1 could be interpreted as definition (5), meaning "they argue *about* different views." However, I believe you intend "they argue *for* different views" instead.

Only (4) and (6) match that meaning. Because (4) is intransitive, it cannot take a direct object, and (6) explicitly takes a subordinate clause. Example 2 is a correct use of (6), while example 1 is incorrect.

**TLDR:** No. Use the subordinate clause *that their views were correct* or the prepositional phrase *for views*.

Answer (score 0):

Well, a google search of the phrase "argue views" came up with only 1,920 hits, most of them being news articles, so I don't believe it is ungrammatical to use views as the object of argue, it does seem a bit uncommon though.

And, to verify that conclusion, I typed "Can they argue views that are not their own?" "They argue the view that is not correct." and "They argue different views" into an online spell-checker, and all entries produced no grammatical commentary and received a grammar score of 100%. (http://spellcheckplus.com/)

So, no, there is nothing ungrammatical or semantically unacceptable about "argue" taking view as its object.